# find the condition on A for the summation to be convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

The summation is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \sqrt { n + 1 } - \sqrt n }{n^A}$$

I don't know how to even begin. Hints??

Comment: I tried to fix your $\TeX$ code, did I correctly?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. typing via phone is PAIN!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** A standard beginning is to multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$.

We end up with 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^A(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}.$$
Now note that $\sqrt{n}\lt \sqrt{n+1}\le 2\sqrt{n}$. From this we obtain
$$     \frac{1}{3n^{A+1/2}}       \lt    \frac{1}{n^A(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\lt \frac{1}{2n^{A+1/2}}.$$
These inequalities should be enough to do the appropriate comparisons with familiar series.

Comment: I did the first step and was wondering if somehow inequalities would help (as done in Sandwich theorem), but didn't know how to get further. The inequality helped! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The first inequality above shows, by Comparison, that we have divergence if $A\ge 1/2$. The second inequality shows there is convergence if $A\lt 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^A}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^A}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac1{n^A\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to both of neat answers, you could use the following facts to find proper values of $A$ as well:

> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}~n^pu_n=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p>1$ and $A$ is finite then $\sum u_n$ converges.
> - If $p\le1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\sum u_n$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, indeed! $\;+(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)$

Comment: This seems interesting, though never had heard anything before about this. Can you please provide further details, or links to them ??

Comment: @ParthThakkar: If you have any access to Schaum's series, see Advanced Calculus.